# Action hook for new pending posts?

Tags: posts, functions, hooks

I'm looking for an action hook to link my function to when a completely new post is created with a status of `pending`?

I'm aware of 'save_post' and others but want to target specifically when a post is new.

Found this on a previous question:

```
add_action('new_to_publish', 'your_function');
add_action('draft_to_publish', 'your_function');
add_action('pending_to_publish', 'your_function');
```

but could do with something like `new_to_pending` or similar?

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I found this whilst searching for the same question over three years later.

I thought I'd answer this incase I find it again in another three years...

Take a look at the docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

The action you need is:

```
{status}_{post_type}
```

So for an `event` post type:

```
function pendingPost($post)
{
   // do something... 
}
add_action('pending_event', 'pendingPost', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the following (/wp-includes/post.php - line 2985):

`do_action( 'transition_post_status', $new_status, $old_status, $post )`